# Sticky, non Sticky CTAs, or both? How to involve UX Research?

Tags: user-research, mobile-application, cta, ux-research

I'm looking for the right UX research method to test 3 CTA cases for a booking application:
1)sticky CTAs 2)non-sticky CTAs (requires scroll) 3)both practices (depending on the purpose of each screen)

We now have sticky CTAs throughout the application and are thinking of implementing non-sticky ones on some screens. Consistency is an important design principle, but how do we know it is always the best practice in every screen of a booking flow?

Which research approach is best to implement in order to make an informed decision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test the effectiveness of the three CTA cases (1) sticky CTAs, (2) non-sticky CTAs, and (3) a combination of both, you can implement a mixed-methods approach using quantitative and qualitative research methods. This will help you make an informed decision based on both performance data and user feedback. Here's a suggested research approach:

- **A/B Testing (Quantitative):** Perform A/B testing on your application
  by creating different versions of the screens with the various CTA
  cases. This will help you compare their performance in terms of
  conversion rates, bounce rates, and other relevant metrics. Ensure
  that you have a large enough sample size to draw statistically
  significant conclusions.
- **Usability Testing (Qualitative):** Conduct usability testing sessions
  with a diverse group of users representing your target audience. Ask
  them to complete specific tasks related to the booking flow while
  using the different versions of the screens. Observe their
  interactions and gather feedback about their experience with the
  CTAs. This will help you understand how users perceive and interact
  with each CTA type in different contexts.
- **Surveys/Interviews (Qualitative):** Collect feedback from users through
  surveys or interviews to gather their opinions and preferences
  regarding the CTAs. This can help you gain insights into the reasons
  behind their preferences and identify potential improvements.
- **Analyze the Data:** Once you have collected the data from A/B testing,
  usability testing, and surveys/interviews, analyze the results to
  identify trends and patterns. Consider the metrics from the
  quantitative research alongside the qualitative feedback from users
  to make an informed decision about which CTA practice is most effective for each screen in the booking flow.

Remember that consistency is important in design, but so is flexibility. If the research findings indicate that non-sticky CTAs perform better on certain screens, it might be worth making an exception to the consistency principle for the sake of improved user experience and higher conversion rates.